Proof of completeness of sufficient statistics for the normal distribution
Random variable $\xi$ is distributed according to the normal law $N(\sqrt{\theta},1)$, $\theta>0$. There are $n$ observations made on the random variable. Find the optimal estimate of the parameter $\theta$.
My solution:
$\xi\sim N(\sqrt{\theta},1)$, $f_{\xi}(x,\theta)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp(-\frac{(x_{j}-\sqrt{\theta})^{2}}{2})$, $\theta>0$
$L(\underline{x},\theta)=\prod_{j=1}^{n}f_{\xi}(x_{j},\theta)=\prod_{j=1}^{n}[\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp(-\frac{(x_{j}-\sqrt{\theta})^{2}}{2})]=const\cdot\exp(-\frac{1}{2}\sum_{j=1}^{n}(x_{j}-\sqrt{\theta})^{2})$
$\bar{L}(\underline{x},\theta)=\ln(L(\underline{x},\theta))=\ln(const)-\frac{1}{2}\sum_{j=1}^{n}(x_{j}-\sqrt{\theta})^{2}$
$\frac{\partial\bar{L}(\underline{x},\theta)}{\partial\theta}=-\frac{1}{2}\sum_{j=1}^{n}2(x_{j}-\sqrt{\theta})(-\frac{1}{2\sqrt{\theta}})=\frac{n}{2\sqrt{\theta}}(\bar{X}-\sqrt{\theta})$
$a(\theta)=\frac{n}{2\sqrt{\theta}}$, $T(\underline{x})=\bar{X}$, $\tau(\theta)=\sqrt{\theta}$
By the efficiency criterion $T(\underline{x})=\bar{X}$ - the efficient estimate for $\tau(\theta)=\sqrt{\theta}$, but for $\theta$ it does not exist.
$L(\underline{x},\theta)=const\cdot\exp(-\frac{1}{2}\sum_{j=1}^{n}(x_{j}-\sqrt{\theta})^{2})=const\cdot\exp(-\frac{1}{2}\sum_{j=1}^{n}x_{j}^{2})\cdot\exp(\sqrt{\theta}n\bar{X}-\frac{n}{2}\theta)$
$h(\underline{x})=const\cdot\exp(-\frac{1}{2}\sum_{j=1}^{n}x_{j}^{2})$, $g(T(\underline{x}),\theta)=\exp(\sqrt{\theta}n\bar{X}-\frac{n}{2}\theta)$
By the factorization criterion $T(\underline{x})=\bar{X}$ is a sufficient statistic.
$E\bar{X}=E[\frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^{n}X_{j}]=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^{n}EX_{j}=\frac{1}{n}n\sqrt{\theta}=\sqrt{\theta}$
$D\bar{X}=D[\frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^{n}X_{j}]=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^{n}DX_{j}=\frac{1}{n}n1=\frac{1}{n}$
So, $\bar{X}\sim N(\sqrt{\theta},\frac{1}{n})$
By the efficiency criterion, $\bar{X}$ is an efficient estimate for $\sqrt{\theta}$, (*) therefore, the optimal estimate for $\sqrt{\theta}$, that is, $\bar{X}$ is a complete sufficient statistic.
$H(T)$: $EH(T)=\theta$ $\forall$ $\theta>0$
$E\bar{X}^{2}=(E\bar{X})^{2}+D\bar{X}=\theta+\frac{1}{n}\neq\theta$
Let $H(T)=\bar{X}^{2}-\frac{1}{n}$
$EH(T)=E[\bar{X}^{2}-\frac{1}{n}]=E\bar{X}^{2}-\frac{1}{n}=\theta+\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n}=\theta$
So, $H(T)=\bar{X}^{2}-\frac{1}{n}$ - optimal estimate for $\theta$
Please tell me if the transition marked with an asterisk is correct?
